# Восстановление позиции элементов после анимации Restore position UIDynamicAnimator

Tags: objective-c, xcode, анимация

Есть анимация элементов (Label, Button, TextField) с помощью UIDynamicAnimator и т.д. После анимации все элементы "валяются" внизу под разными углами. Как сделать возврат их на исходное место, как было до анимации?

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    UIDynamicAnimator *animatir;
    UIGravityBehavior *gravity;
    UICollisionBehavior *collision;
    UIDynamicItemBehavior *bounce;

}
@end
```

.
.
.

```
-(IBAction) buttonPressed: (id) sender {
animatir = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc]initWithReferenceView:self.view];
    gravity = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems: @[label1, label2, label3, Edit1, Ediit2, Button2]];
    [animatir addBehavior:gravity];

    collision = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc]initWithItems:@[label1, label2, label3, Edit1, Ediit2, Button2]];
    collision.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = YES;
    [animatir addBehavior:collision];

    bounce = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc]initWithItems:@[label1, label2, label3, Edit1, Ediit2, Button2]];
    bounce.elasticity = 0.90;
    [animatir addBehavior:bounce];

}
```

Comment: Предлагаю закрыть как решенный. ТС видимо зашел под другим аккаунтом, значит от этого пароль не помнит.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько мне известно, UIKitDynamics не отвечает за хранение истории состояний объектов.

Если используется Autolayout, то можно вернуть состояние довольно просто

```
- (void)resetToInitialState {
    NSArray *objects = @[self.label1, self.label2, self.label3, self.textField1, self.textField2, self.button];

    // Очищаем все behavior у аниматора
    [self.animator removeAllBehaviors];

    // Обновляем layout
    [self.view setNeedsLayout];

    // Далее отменяем все трансформации. Если этого не сделать, то все вьюшки будут повернуты
    [objects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *view, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }];
}
```

Если без Autolayout, то нужно сохранять параметр frame у всех объектов и затем возвращать значения при возврате.